# I have an array of objects and will like to alter the value if the type is a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have this so far, but when I check people after it doesn't alter the age keys values to prepend "$".I want to assume I dont know which values are of type of number, so I want to do a check and change it to have $23, $3, $8 etc.

```
const people = [
    {name: 'John', age: 23, sex: "male"}, 
    {name: 'Andrew', age: 3, sex: "male"}, 
    {name: 'Peter', age: 8, sex: "male"}, 
    {name: 'Hanna', age: 14, sex: "male"}, 
    {name: 'Adam', age: 37, sex: "male"}];


let indVals;

people.forEach(function(arr) {
    indVals = Object.values(arr);
    console.log('Individual values: ',indVals);
    for(let val of indVals) {
        if ( typeof val === "number") {
            val = "$" + val;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to prepend it, and alter it to have $ in front of it

Comment: `val` is a copy of the property value. Changing its content won't modify the value of the property in the object.

Comment: Is this a generalization of a problem? Or you only want to upgrade the age property? If so you can basically use `arr.age = '$' + arr.age`. If you want a generic solution you may need keys instead of values.

Comment: I want to assume that I dont know which key has values as type of numbers, hence the reason I am checking with typeof

Comment: Iterate over the keys (`Object.keys()`, `for...in...`) instead of the values

Answer (score 1):

Since op stated that property names are not known. You need to use keys to get the properties then check the type and then update the value using the key.

```js
 const people = [
{name: 'John', age: 23, sex: "male"}, 
{name: 'Andrew', age: 3, sex: "male"}, 
{name: 'Peter', age: 8, sex: "male"}, 
{name: 'Hanna', age: 14, sex: "male"}, 
{name: 'Adam', age: 37, sex: "male"}];

people.forEach(obj=> {
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>{   
    if (typeof obj[key] === "number") {
      obj[key] = "$" + obj[key];
    }
  });
});

console.log(people);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` the `people` array and conditionally modify the value of a property in an object. Note that using `map` will give you a new array.

```js
const people = [
    {name: 'John', age: 23, sex: "male"}, 
    {name: 'Andrew', age: 3, sex: "male"}, 
    {name: 'Peter', age: 8, sex: "male"}, 
    {name: 'Hanna', age: 14, sex: "male"}, 
    {name: 'Adam', age: 37, sex: "male"}];
    
    
const result = people.map(obj => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => {
   return (typeof v === 'number') ? [k, `$${v}`] : [k, v];
  }));
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
res = people.map((elem) => {
    for(let key in elem){
        if(typeof elem[key] == 'number'){
            elem[key] += '$';
        }
    }
    return elem;
})
```